# Interactive(clickable) map

Tags: c#, winforms, svg

I have a map of a camping, this is it:

[image]

Now, on this map, there are a lot of camping places. And all of the places(yellow, pink and the striped yellow), need to be clickable.

So my question is, how would i achieve this? I was thinking about using SVG or something. Is this a good solution?

Comment: Either go for imagemaps or see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701778/make-a-map-of-buttons/25703170?s=1|0.6909#25703170) (solution 2) for an example!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic idea: Create a **color map** to look up which spot the user has clicked.

To create that color map, start with the original map, overlay it with an empty bitmap and write a small tool application to help you:

- it should let you paint a filled circle in a special color for each site spot
- ideally those colors should allow you to re-construct the number and type of the places
- upon each click the next color should be prepared
- you don't need to match the place too exactly, but it is up to you to improve the colormap with a paint program; put the orginal map in a layer under it and use an eyedropper tool to get the right color and then draw the places a little better
- as many of the places have consecutive numbers you can

  - count them up with each click
  - use an input box to set new starting numbers

For the actual application you should

- hold the color map in memory
- use the `MouseClick` of a `PictureBox` to get the coordinates of the place
- multiply (or rather divide) those with the zoom factor
- use `GetPixel` on the color map to get the color and then
- extract the place number.

An `ARGB` color has 3 color bytes; two will suffice for the place numbers and you will still have one byte for the color coded types of places..

The zoom factor is `1f * PictureBox.clientSize.Width / PictureBox.Image.Width`.

For best user experience I would use the `PictureBox.MouseMove` to look up the place in the color map and give **feedback** whenever the color changes, including setting and clearing the `mouse cursor` betwenn `Hand` and `Default` whenever the location is clickable, i.e. has a non-transparent color on the color map..

To avoid artifacts the color map must be stored as`PNG` , not as `JPG`!

If you want more info with the places you could (and should) create a `Place` class and hold a `Dictionary<Color, Place>` to look up `Place` by `Color`..

Answer (score 0):

If you put the image in a `PictureBox`, say, you could use the `MouseClick` event.

Comment: Yes that's true, but i have to create regions or something for every place(so that would take a long time with mouseLocation), and i need to take into a count that it needs to be resizeable

Comment: Well, resizability is "easy". Convert from pixel to picture co-ordinates like this `x=Mouse.X/Picture.Width`. but I can't think of a short cut to define regions, unless you can detect colour of pixel, if that helps.