# Sending SMS in Twilio C# 2010

Tags: c#, sms, twilio

I have this code:

```
// Your Account SID from twilio.com/console
var accountSid = "ACabcdefgb82406abcdefg40051234579";
// Your Auth Token from twilio.com/console
var authToken = "abcdefgde123456788db07e48a5123458";

TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

var message = MessageResource.Create(
    to: new PhoneNumber("+639971071359"),
    from: new PhoneNumber("+639357557459"),
    body: "Hello from C#");
```

but I have five errors:
[image]

It's my first time to encounter this kind of error so I don't have an idea how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which .net framework your project is targeting to?

Comment: Are you building this on Windows? Which version of Visual Studio?

Comment: wrt to the just deleted question you may want ot have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33478564/interactiveclickable-map/33480232#33480232)