# Click on image and show message box depending on the clicked place

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this idea of this world map image and when I click a country on it, it shows information of that country in a `MessageBox` for example does anyone have an idea how to do that?

I have a rectangle and a button and when i click the button it shows the image in the rectangle but i thought if i use polygons to shape the country's but I'm a little stuck.

[image: World Map]

I would like to have every country apart and maybe that the borders light up when clicked

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33478564/interactiveclickable-map/33480232?s=1|5.6935#33480232) for a simple but usable idea.. The same [idea is also discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701778/make-a-map-of-buttons/25703170?s=2|0.6937#25703170)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily using WPF:

1. Find a nice World Map in SVG format. I used [this one](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:World_map_-_low_resolution.svg) from Wikipedia:

[image: World Map Wikipedia]

2. Download and install [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/download/) then open the SVG you've just downloaded. Inkscape has a nice feature that makes it possible to save an SVG as a XAML.

[image: InkScape save dialog]

3. Import the `ViewBox` from the XAML file into your WPF window/etc:

[image: VS XAML editor]

4. For each `Path` in the XAML you can add a `MouseEnter`/`MouseLeave` event handler or you can use the same one for all the `Path`s

Sample code:

```
 private void CountryMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
     var path = sender as Path;
     if (path != null)
     {
         path.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aqua);
     }
 }

 private void Country_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
     var path = sender as Path;
     if (path != null)
     {
         path.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
     }
 }
```

5. Now it's just a matter of changing colors/showing `MessageBox`es etc.

   [image: Demo]

[GitHub](https://github.com/0xffffabcd/WorldMapViewer)

Comment: dude thanks so much this was the nicest answer I have seen on stackoverflow since I use it

Comment: @Sanscull glad you like it. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

My first thought: You could bind a command to the view that will be triggered by a click on a position. If you're using WPF you can bind command parameters to the command to get the x and y of your click...
After that you have to handle the content of your messagebox and the highlighting of the borders depending on the position xy.

have fun :D

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

There is a project on Code Project that someone created that defines hotspots that are clickable with events. You could use that to overlay your map and define the hotspots where you need them.

[C# Windows Forms ImageMap Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2820/C-Windows-Forms-ImageMap-Control)

**Option 2**

You could bind to the `MouseUp` Event on the Image and use the following to see if it is in a `Rectangle`

```
private void mapMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
    Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(0, 100, 100, 100);
    if (rect1.Contains(e.Location)) {
        // Do your stuff
    } else if (rect2.Contains(e.Location)) {
        // Do your stuff
    }
}
```