# click on different part of picturebox (c#)

Tags: c#, events, click, picturebox, windows-forms-designer

Can anyone please teach me how to detect the event of "clicking on certain part of the same picture" in C#(WindowsForm, to be specific)?

For example, let's just say we have a brain picture in picturebox, and there are three different regions on it : hippocampus, frontal lobe and cortex.
How should I detect which region is clicked by user?
(Those regions are in irregular shapes.)

Thanks!

Comment: Oh...I'm sorry...I just thought that I could ask for help...
(cuz' I've found some questions similar to this...)

Comment: Also [see here!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701778/make-a-map-of-buttons/25703170#25703170)

Comment: There are lots of ways to do hit-testing. If you want to ask about it here, you have to do some research, try something, and then make sure you include a good [mcve] in your question showing what you've tried, and explain precisely what _specific_ issue you are having trouble solving. Note that the Winforms API does include a `Region` object that supports hit testing via e.g. the [`IsVisible(Point)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz11htdf(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your picture has different colors, if you want similar looking colors make you colors like this: `Color.FromArgb(10, 10, 10)` and `Color.FromArgb(10, 10, 11)`.

In your click method get the cursor x, y coords *(on the screen)* and use this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/753157/6438653), which will return the color of the pixel.

Set up a switch case or if block, that will determine which part you clicked by the color.

*Sorry that there's no code...*

Comment: _"Make sure your picture has different colors"_ - well brain CT scans are generally grayscale

Comment: Then you could change the grayscale colors slightly like `Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255)` and `Color.FromArgb(254, 254, 254)`.

Comment: No because it's entirely possible that the same pixel intensity (say xf0f0f0) could appear in different regions of the brain.

Comment: Okay, true, but what if it's a flat style image, where it's all plain colors?        *(Like a .png or .bmp image.)*

Comment: Yes agreed then it's totally acceptable. :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the coloring idea. I think it will work in my case.
Those pictures I got are not CT scans. But thanks for your reply anyway.